# what does grave accent ` and aposrophe ' do in elisp regular expression?

Tags: regular-expressions

I use `C-h v` to check the doc about this variable `org-agenda-file-regexp`.

It says it is a variable defined in `org.el`.
Its value is

```
"\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'"
```

What is the meaning of grave accent `` ` `` and aposrophe `'` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Regexp-Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html)

> `` \` ``
>
> matches the empty string, but only at the beginning of the buffer or string being matched against.
>
> `\'`
>
> matches the empty string, but only at the end of the buffer or string being matched against.